# Practice of higher categories - giving rigorous constructions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories, higher-algebra

1) Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a monoidal $\infty$-category, $A$ an algebra object in $\mathcal{C}$, and $M$ a left $A$-module in $\mathcal{C}$. So, in Lurie's formalism, $\mathcal{C}$ is encoded by some coCartesian fibration $f: \mathcal{C}^{\otimes} \to I$, where $I$ is a suitable index category. $A$ is encoded by a suitable section of $f$, and $M$ is encoded by yet another section, of a suitable $g : \mathcal{C}^{\otimes, mod} \to J$ (this $g$ encodes $\mathcal{C}$ being a left module over $\mathcal{C}$).

2) Now, suppose that $M$ is dualizible as an object of $\mathcal{C}$ (let's ignore the difference between left and right duals). I want to say that $M^{\vee}$ is naturally a right $A$-module. Intuitively, it is enough to specify maps $M^{\vee} \otimes A^{\otimes n} \to M^{\vee}$, which are the same as maps $M^{\vee} \otimes A^n \otimes M \to \mathbb{1}$, which are given by collapsing using $M$'s module structure and then evaluating: $M^{\vee} \otimes A^n \otimes M \to M^{\vee} \otimes M \to \mathbb{1}$.

3) But rigorously, one needs more - one needs to construct a section again, presumably in fact constructing a contractible space of options for each value of the section, etc. etc. For me, it looks very cumbersome to do this even for such a "simple construction", for at least the following reasons:

(a) If I did this for some $M$, I might realize after some time that in fact I want this to be functorial in $M$, hence needing to return to the construction and alter it in yet another level of sophistication.

b) It seems that I will have difficulty to characterize the construction so that it will not be dependent on the specific model of higher categories used.

(c) The amount of somewhat creative thinking needed for such "foundational" aspects would be too unreasonably huge to be able to get to non-foundational things.

4) If I understand correctly, if you look at papers using these things (for example, Gaitsgory or Ben-Zvi Nadler and related), they don't actually get into such things, and simply use the objects as one would think is probably permissible.

So, my questions is vaguely about the philosophy behind this, how one should think. But to be precise, just as an example, one can say that I ask about putting a right module structure on the dual of a left module.

Comment: It's like in all formalisms: at first you want to give painstakingly explicit constructions. The more you use the formalism, the more you become familiar and the more constructions you find so "obvious" that they do not need to be spelled out (in the sense that you would be able to give the details at a moment's notice if needed). Now, there is a certain level of clunkiness in the subject, but part of it is that you're carrying around so much structure that it is almost miraculous how compact you can be.

Comment: For the general question: very few constructions can be done by hand, almost everything needs to be handled by manipulating universal properties. The particular question is covered in Section 4.6.2 of my book "Higher Algebra" (see in particular Proposition 4.6.2.13 and the surrounding discussion). Roughly speaking, the idea is to first define what it means to have a duality which is compatible with left and right actions of $A$, and then to show that this notion is compatible with forgetting the $A$-actions.

Comment: @JacobLurie: Oh, I see (for some reason I didn't think the section deal with that judging by it's title), thanks.